# Mapping Many to many in Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

simply I ask this How to Map , How to ProductCustomer in the sample ??

```
 public class ProductCustomer
    {
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

and about Product and Customer :

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }

public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create the ProductCustomer object.

In EF, you create your Customer and Product, and then you create collections to each.  This will automatically create the proper link tables.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
}
```

This is only the case, however, if your link table has no payload (has no additional data).  If it does, then you will need to create the link table as an entity similar to what you originally did, but you add 1:many links in your product and customer classes to the link entity.  You then have to modify your queries to query through the link table.